# How to place things into an array of hashes based on property value?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm trying to place these `tools` into the right group hash object in this array. I'm not sure how to do this with Ruby.

```
groups = [
  { group: 'Business Training', tools: [] },
  { group: 'Human Resources', tools: [] },
  { group: 'Clean', tools: [] },
  { group: 'Example', tools: [] }
]

tools = [
  { name: "Foo", group: "Clean", id: 1 },
  { name: "Bar", group: "Clean", id: 2 },
  { name: "Baz", group: "Business Training", id: 3 },
]
```

---

I want to end up with a structure like this:

```
groups = [
  { 
    group: 'Business Training', 
    tools: [
      { name: "Baz", group: "Business Training", id: 3 },
    ] 
  },
  { group: 'Human Resources', tools: [] },
  { 
    group: 'Clean', 
    tools: [
      { name: "Foo", group: "Clean", id: 1 },
      { name: "Bar", group: "Clean", id: 2 },
    ] 
  },
  { group: 'Example', tools: [] }
]
```

Comment: Please read "[ask]", the linked pages, and "[mcve]". You've given us input and showed us your desired output but forgot to show us your attempt to solve the problem. We need the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you, which isn't what SO is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tools.each do |tool|
  group = groups.find { |item| item[:group] == tool[:group] }
  group[:tools] << tool
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = groups.map do |group|
  {
    group: group[:group],
    tools: tools.select do |tool|
      tool[:group] == group[:group]
    end
  }
end
puts result
```

Which prints:

```
{:group=>"Business Training", :tools=>[{:name=>"Baz", :group=>"Business Training", :id=>3}]}
{:group=>"Human Resources", :tools=>[]}
{:group=>"Clean", :tools=>[{:name=>"Foo", :group=>"Clean", :id=>1}, {:name=>"Bar", :group=>"Clean", :id=>2}]}
{:group=>"Example", :tools=>[]}
```

Comment: This obviously won't work if `groups` has keys other than `:group` and `:tools`. The OP did not ask for that, but why not provide the generality in case the spec changes in the future, particularly when it is so easy to accommodate?

Answer (score 0):

One more solution:

```
groups.each do |group|
   group[:tools] = 
      tools.select { |tool| tool[:group] == group[:group] }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = tools.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:group]] = g }
  #=> { "Clean"            =>{:name=>"Bar", :group=>"Clean", :id=>2},
  #     "Business Training"=>{:name=>"Baz", :group=>"Business Training", :id=>3}} 
groups.map { |g| g.update(tools: h[g[:group]]) }
  #=> [{:group=>"Business Training",
  #     :tools=>{:name=>"Baz", :group=>"Business Training", :id=>3}},
  #    {:group=>"Human Resources",
  #     :tools=>nil},
  #    {:group=>"Clean",
  #     :tools=>{:name=>"Bar", :group=>"Clean", :id=>2}},
  #    {:group=>"Example",
  #     :tools=>nil}]
```

Constructing the hash `h` requires only a single pass through `tools`. For each element of `groups` this permits a simple hash value replacement, which is faster than methods that search though `tools` for each element of `groups` or vice-versa.

Notice that, as well as mutating `groups`, this returns the updated value. If you do not wish to modify `groups` replace [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) with [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge).